# Android: onClick and OnFocusChange interaction

Tags: android, validation, onclick

I have `EditText` field and a `Button`. 
I have `onFocusChanged` attached to the `EditText` field, and `onClick` attached to the `Button`.

So when the button is clicked the `EditText` loses focus, and the `onFocusChanged` is executed, and then the `onClick` of the button is executed. The thing is I need validation of the `EditText` value and I do this validation in the `onFocusChanged`, but if the validation fails, I want to CANCEL the `onClick` action of the button.

How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe you could use a `TextWatcher` to validate the content and enable/ disable the `Button` according to the validation status

Comment: Thanks! I have considered this, but I don't like it very much, so if there is another way I'd like to find it out.

Comment: Ok.. then why don't you make the validation in `onClick`? This is the best way to do it and the easiest one since you can forget about tracking how all the listeners are called and how you can cancel them

Comment: Because focus can be lost not ONLY by clicking this button, and the validation should still be done if the focus is lost in another way. Thanks for your help, though! And for the formatting fixes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a shared boolean isValid, onFocusChange sets it to whatever you want it to, and onClick checks that boolean before it does anything,
You should also remember to set isValid to false whenever you make a change.

The problem with that solution is that depending on the scheduling, it might execute onClick before onFocusChange (I'm not sure about that, but just in case), I would define another boolean beingEdited, onFocusChange sets it yo false, and whenever the text is being edited, true, onClick would check if the text is being edited before it checks if it's valid, and it's being edited, it would wait on that boolean, onFocusChange should also wake whoever wants on beingEdited

Comment: I was hoping for a "native" solution. But since it seems there isn't one, I think I am going to use your idea. It fits my needs.Thanks!